# Modify PeoplePicker to remove AD results and only show SAML Claims?

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, adfs, claims, saml

Is there a way to completely remove the default Active Directory results from showing in the SP people picker and only have the SAML claims show? It seems like I can filter result sets using stsadm.exe or powershell equivalents but not completely exclude it. When you search for a user you get two results, the typical AD account and the AD FS Users result 'account'.

A work around I was thinking of was to create an empty OU and only filter results based on that so that nothing comes up. For whatever reason the results in the people picker still came back the same, using `UserAccountDirectoryPath`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use https://ldapcp.codeplex.com/ codeplex Custom Claim Provider then you can use the following script to hide however this will hide in entire farm.

```
$cpm = Get-SPClaimProviderManager
$ad = get-spclaimprovider -identity "AD"
$ad.IsVisible = $false
$cpm.Update()
```

Otherwise you can extend the website to different zone than disable NTLM Authentication.

Have a look to this post:
[Hide AD claims provider in a specific web app](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167468/hide-ad-claims-provider-in-a-specific-web-app)

Comment: The script doesn't require LDAPCP, it works perfectly without it. Thanks! I played around with LDAPCP a bit on my test environment, it seems awesome but a bit out of scope for now, maybe I'll have some more use for it later.